# Magento 2 data migration fail (Notice: Undefined offset 1 Eav/Data.php on line 209)

Tags: magento2

we're migrating 1.8.1.0 to Magento 2.1. When we go to migrate data, I hit this error:

```
[2016-07-18 18:40:19][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:19][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:19][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Settings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:22][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Stores Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:22][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:22][bin/magento migrate:data -r vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.8.1.0/config.xml
Reset the current position of migration to start from the beginning

[2016-07-18 18:40:29][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:29][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:30][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: PostProcessing Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-07-18 18:40:38][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
28% [========>-------------------] Remaining Time: 1 sec


  [Exception]
  Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/vhosts/magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 209
```

Has anyone come across this and any solutions?

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Any solution???